# Why cant i get the field nodeId from account

Tags: apex, sobject

I have this object from which i can get the name by:`ATN[i].account.Name` if i use `ATN[i].account.nodeId` i I get the error: Invalid field nodeId for SObject Account, the object is `(ObjectStructureMap:[account=Account:{OwnerId=00537000000aLrZAAU, Name=United Partners Holding, Id=00137000002hZpNAAU, RecordTypeId=01237000000I4h8AAC}, closeFlag=(), currentNode=true, levelFlag=(), nodeId=0, nodeType=start])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your `ObjectStructureMap`, you should try with this:

```
ATN[i].nodeId
```